# How can i clear particular text in text mode in c++ "not whole screen"?

Tags: c++

```
system("cls") - #include <stdlib.h>  STANDARD HEADER FILE 
clrscr()      - #include <conio.h>   NON-STANDARD HEADER FILE
```

These two functions clear whole screen.
I wanted to clear or we can using the concept of BACKSLASH '\b' for a particular character or string without effecting the other content.At the time of inserting any number.
For Example : hellow 
as i typing this 'hellow' at the same time it goes back to 'o'.

Comment: Note that even though `system` is provided by the C standard, its behavior is implementation-defined. Neither C or C++ have anything to say about graphical text manipulation. Use something like ncurses.

Comment: Windows provides an API for working with the console:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010(v=vs.85).aspx.  I don't think you erase text, though.  I think you just write spaces over what you want to erase.

Comment: I think that any answers would have to be operating-system-/output device-specific. For example, `system("cls")` would not work in bash (`sh: 1: cls: not found`).

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Give us an example (input, output).

Comment: Two Types of Mode i have know that is text and graphic mode in graphic mode i can do it just by setting up gotoxy(x,y) but in text mode i got nothing yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following C programs work in bash on Debian:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("xxxHellow\bxxx\n");
  return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() { return system("echo 'xxxHellow\bxxx'"); }
```

Both produce the result you'd expect:

```
thomas@yozu-thomas:~/Programming$ gcc -o main main.c
thomas@yozu-thomas:~/Programming$ ./main
xxxHelloxxx
thomas@yozu-thomas:~/Programming$
```

This will probably work on Mac OSX too (since it also uses [bash](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html)), but I don't know about Windows [`cmd.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) or [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SetConsoleCursorPos()` function that is inside the `windows.h` library and overwrite a character or more characters with blank characters/spaces through calling a text printing function.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void clearScreen(int from_x, int to_x, int from_y, int to_y) // this function clears a block of text
{
    HANDLE conHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    for(int i = 0; i<to_y-from_y; i++)
    {
        COORD pos;
        pos.Y = from_y+i;
        pos.X = from_x;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(conHandle, pos);
        for(int j = 0; j<to_x-from_x; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<10; j++)
        {
            printf("a");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    clearScreen(1, 3, 4, 6);
    return 0;
}
```